# How do I read contents of a file, and if the words repeat in the file add them to a list?

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a free Inventory System and I can't seem to fiquire out how to read a files contents. Take the words, if any are matching add a number to them. So if say "Sticks" shows up 3 times in the file have it print to console. "Sticks : 3"

```
void ViewFiles() {
  string line;
  ifstream a_file("Candles");
  if (a_file.is_open())
  {
    while (getline(a_file, line))
    {
      cout << line << '\n';
      if (line == line) {
        line = line + "1";
      }
    }
    a_file.close();
  }
  else cout << "Unable to open file";
}
```

I am sorry if the code is bad this is my first real project for myself.

Comment: Such short code snippets are better directly copied into the question. The input form has a separate button for entering code.

Comment: Consider what `if (line == line)` *means* (i.e. is there *ever* a time that is *not* true?).

Comment: 1)Make an fstream of your file to read its contents. 2)create hash map using - map<string,int> hash; 3)get word from ypur fstream and do hash[word]++; 4)Now, you only need to traverse map once at end and output the key with data in your required format

Comment: Okay i read your code now. I think instead of getline() you should simply use a_file>>str; This function will by itself fetch a word only with spliters being spaces and new line characters

Answer (score 1):

Simply use a map.
You can do:

```
map<string, int> someName;
```

whenever you find a new word, use it as a key:

```
someName[word]++; //you found it so increment the occurrence;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 loops. Add another one inside the while to compare the first word with the rest of the list. If you find the same word you add 1 to the counter. When you finish you print that word and the counter and look for the second word...